# Magento 2.3 Inject helper into controller object type error?

Tags: magento2.3

Sorry I am new to M2, I am having error whenever I load helper class into controller. I searched every online but no luck. Here is the setup and error when I load

**Setup: Magento 2.3 Server Centos 7 / PHP7.2 / Local VM**

> Error Trace
>
> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object:
>   Custom\Payment\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object:
>   Custom\Payment\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor
>       #0  /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Custom\Payment\...',
>   Array)
>       #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Custom\Payment\...',
>   Array)
>       #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(44):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Custom\Payment\...')
>       #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(304):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Custom\Payment\...')
>       #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(165):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http),
>   Array)
>       #5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)
>       #8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #13 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)
>       #14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #15 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
>       #16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
>       #17 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>       #18 {main}

**Helper Code**

```
namespace Custom\Payment\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class General extends AbstractHelper
{

    public function RandomFunc()
       {
               echo "This is Helper in Magento 2";
       }

}
```

**Controller Code**

```
namespace Custom\Payment\Controller\Index;

use Custom\Payment\Helper\General as CustomHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
        CustomHelper $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->helper->RandomFunc();
    }
}
```

Anyone could enlighten me where I did wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: try to remove folder var/generator from your root folder

Comment: have you ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`? Or delete `generated/code/YourModule` manually.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have an issue at   `__construct(`.

You must pass the context object  `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context` to the
parent  class `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    CustomHelper $helper
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
parent::__construct($context);
}
```

***after these changes, when in developer mode, just remove the folders under var/generation/ or generated/ [as the documentation suggests](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html)***

***or run setup:di:compile when in production mode***

---

Comment: `./bin/magento setup:di:compile` was the thing, thanks

Answer (score 25):

Just Remove the Generation folder or in version 2.2 remove the generated folder.

rm -rf generated/

Flush the cache.
It should work then. Its because the interceptor file needs to be re-created or refresh.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Amit Bera's answer, make sure that if you're adding any new parameters to the __construct() method that you add them before any parameters with default values (like null) defined.

Answer (score 0):

Run the di complie and cache flush commands

```
php bin/magento s:d:c

Php bin/magento c:c

Php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor file needs to be re-create. So kindly run di:compile and clean cache

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento  c:f

//Or 

rm -rf generated/
```

Its worked for me