# Magento 2.3 Class VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory does not exist

Tags: magento2.3

[Object Type Error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252969/magento-2-3-inject-helper-into-controller-object-type-error) [image]

As per the above link to overcome the Object Type Error I have to run the command `php bin/magento s:d:c`  after I run the command I got error like
[image: Screen Shots]
.
**Code**

```
<?php
namespace Sathya\LoadProduct\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; // constructor
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; // Controller class

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product; // Model Method
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;  // Repository Method
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory; // Factory Method
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product as ResourceProduct;
class Index extends Action
{
    protected  $productId = 500, $productModel, $_productFactory, $_productRepository,$ResourceProduct;
    public function __construct(Context $context, Product $productModel,ResourceProduct $ResourceProduct,ProductFactory $_productFactory, ProductRepositoryInterface $_productRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productModel = $productModel;
        $this->ResourceProduct = $ResourceProduct;
        $this->_productFactory = $_productFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $_productRepository;
        $this->getProductRepository();
        $this->getProductModel();
        $this->getProductFactory();
    }
    public function getProductModel()
    {
       $product = $this->productModel;
       $this->ResourceProduct->load($product,$this->productId);
        $product->setName("ram's phant");
        $this->ResourceProduct->save($product);

                     echo $product->getName()."<br>";
    }
    public function getProductFactory()
    {
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
        $this->ResourceProduct->load($product,$this->productId);
        $product->setName("ram's phant");
        $this->ResourceProduct->save($product);
        echo $product->getName()."<br>";
    }
    public function getProductRepository()
    {
        $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($this->productId);
        echo $product->getName()."<br>";

    }
    public function execute()   {    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to remove generated dir?

Comment: no, never I tried

Comment: namespace Sathya\LoadProduct\Controller\Index; this path is incorrect it should be
namespace Sathya\LoadProduct\Index

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I got the solution. @ASQ

Answer (score 0):

Remove the generated directory by running the following command

```
rm -rf generated/
```

**EDIT**

Your namespace path is incorrect it should be

```
namespace Sathya\LoadProduct\Index
```

Comment: still, the same error repeating.

Comment: can you please share your code, i think you had given the wrong path

Comment: yeah sure as of now I'm in learning phase so I tried to use all the method to load the data from table.